# Draw parabola with MetaPost

Tags: metapost

I keep getting this error:
"! A tertiary expression can't begin with `['."

```
beginfig(1);
numeric u,a,x;
vardef yb(expr x)=
    x*x-6*x+8;
enddef;
pair igreka[],igrekb[];
path paraboola,paraboolb;
u := 1cm;
drawarrow (-4u,0u)--(6u,0u);
drawarrow (0u,-4u)--(0u,9u);
for i=0 upto 16:
    igreka[i]:=((i/2)*u,((i/2)**2-6*(i/2)+8)*u);
endfor;
paraboola:=igreka[0]..igreka[1]..igreka[2]..igreka[3]..[igreka[4]..igreka[9]..igreka[10]..igreka[11]..igreka[13]..igreka[14]..igreka[15]..igreka[16];
draw paraboola;
endfig;
```

I'm trying to draw a parabola, but I'm not able to draw a path with the list shown in my code, the list igreka[].

I'd also like to know if there's a way to define the path of the parabola in some easier way via some for cycle such that:

```
beginfig(1);
numeric u,a,x;
vardef yb(expr x)=
    x*x-6*x+8;
enddef;
pair igreka[],igrekb[];
path paraboola,paraboolb;
u := 1cm;
drawarrow (-4u,0u)--(6u,0u);
drawarrow (0u,-4u)--(0u,9u);
for i=0 upto 16:
    igreka[i]:=((i/2)*u,((i/2)**2-6*(i/2)+8)*u);
endfor;
EXAMPLE HERE: for i=1 upto 16:
    paraboola:=igrek[1]..igrek[2].. ..igrek[16];
endfor;
draw paraboola;
endfig;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first issue was just a typo: you wrote `[igreka[4]` instead of `igreka[4]`. So MetaPost complains that you shouldn't begin your expression with a `[`.

MetaPost, similar to TeX, is a macro based language. Therefore control structures like `for` are not restricted to have full statements in their body, their body can also contain partial statement like `.. igreka[i]`.

```
beginfig(1);
numeric u,a,x;
vardef yb(expr x)=
    x*x-6*x+8;
enddef;
pair igreka[],igrekb[];
path paraboola,paraboolb;
u := 1cm;
drawarrow (-4u,0u)--(6u,0u);
drawarrow (0u,-4u)--(0u,9u);
for i=0 upto 16:
    igreka[i]:=((i/2)*u,((i/2)**2-6*(i/2)+8)*u);
endfor;
paraboola := igreka[0]
    for i=1 upto 16: .. igreka[i] endfor;
draw paraboola;
endfig;
bye;
```

Answer (score 2):

I know this is old, and I see that the original answer fixed the issues in the OP, but in case anyone comes here hoping to find a good way to “draw a parabola with Metapost”, I thought it might be worth adding another solution, that is perhaps a bit more generic.

[image]

This is wrapped up in `luamplib` and makes use of the `mplibtextextlabel` magic, so you need to compile it with `lualatex`.

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{luamplib}
\begin{document}
\mplibtextextlabel{enable}
\begin{mplibcode}
beginfig(1);

    path ff;  % first the function and its curve
    vardef f(expr x) = x * x - 6 * x + 8 enddef;
    ff = (0, f(0)) for x = 1 upto 12: .. (x, f(x)) endfor;
   
    % scale the curve nicely in each dimension
    numeric u, v; u = 20; v = 2;
    ff := ff xscaled u yscaled v;

    % this is just one way to make nice axes
    path xx, yy;
    bboxmargin := 20pt;
    xx = subpath (0, 1) of bbox ff;
    xx := xx shifted (0, -ypart point 0 of xx);
    yy = subpath (4, 3) of bbox ff;
    yy := yy shifted (-xpart point 0 of yy, 0);

    % draw and label the function curve
    draw ff withcolor 2/3 red;
    label.top("$y=x^2 - 6x + 8$", point infinity of ff) 
        withcolor 2/3 red;

    % draw and label the axes
    drawarrow xx; label.rt("$x$", point 1 of xx);
    drawarrow yy; label.top("$y$", point 1 of yy);

    % add some scales along the axes
    for x = 2 step 2 until 12:
        draw (x * u, 0) -- (x * u, -3);
        label.bot("$" & decimal x & "$", (x * u, -3));
    endfor
    for y = 20 step 20 until 80:
        draw (0, y * v) -- (-3, y * v);
        label.lft("$" & decimal y & "$", (-3, y * v));
    endfor

endfig;
\end{mplibcode}
\end{document}
```